# Moving sprite in Andengine

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, racing

I made a racing game in [andengine](http://www.andengine.org/).The car is moving by MoveModifier().The car is dynamicBody at the same time.But the dynamicBody characteristic of car is losing when it is moving.

> (enemy1=car)

```
Sprite enemy1=new Sprite(0,0,this.enemyRegion1);
         enemy1.registerEntityModifier(
                    (IEntityModifier) new SequenceEntityModifier (
                            new MoveModifier(10, enemy1.getX(),  enemy1.getX()+400, 
                                    enemy1.getY(), enemy1.getY())));
        final Vector2 velocity = Vector2Pool.obtain(5, 5);

        final FixtureDef enemyFixtureDef1 = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0);
        this.enemyBody1 = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, enemy1, BodyType.DynamicBody, enemyFixtureDef1);
        this.enemyBody1.setLinearVelocity(velocity);
        Vector2Pool.recycle(velocity);
        this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(enemy1, this.enemyBody1, true, false));






        this.scene.attachChild(enemy1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot move physics bodies using MoveModifier, it only works with Sprites without a PhysicsConnector. The connection goes only one way, from the Box2D engine to AndEngine that works on top of it. You will have to manage the car movement in terms of physics and the sprite will follow the body. Not the other way round.

Comment: so how can the body follow a known path? Which function in box2d?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629524/making-a-box2d-object-follow-a-predetermined-path The accepted answer should work.

Comment: I know the coordinates.but which function will I use to move it to coordinates I know?  For example: body.move(10,10);

Comment: If you want to move it instantly, use body.setTransform(parameters). If you choose to use MouseJoint, then it will be mousejoint.setTarget(coords).