# making a box2d body move in a sine wave type motion

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, physics, box2d-iphone

How can I make a box2d body move in a sine wave type motion? I believe it will require applying some forces to move it along the sine curve path but I am not sure how. I would really appreciate any guidelines to make this possible.

Comment: you could apply sine to body's gravityScale property so that it fluctuates between 1 and -1

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: I would appreciate really a code example of this

Comment: I don't know box2d, so I'll make this a comment. Do you know how to apply a force to the body? Do you know how to generate a sine wave (i.e. `sin(t)` for t = 0.01, 0.02, 0.03...)? It is an interesting property of sine waves that a sinusoidal *force* produces a sinusoidal *motion* (unlike, say, a square wave).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: I am trying to implement your approach but I don't fully understand it, especially the setting of the gravityscale. I also thought a force with some (x, sinx) would work. Will the gravity scale be changing every tick? how do I make it fluctuate between 1 and -1? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it, but the mouse joint solution provided in [Making a Box2d object follow a predetermined path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629524/making-a-box2d-object-follow-a-predetermined-path) seems elegant and should work.

You may have a little delay on the move, but it will seem more "natural".

If you want an exact move, look at : [making a box2d body move along a Bezier curve/ arc path](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35553/making-a-box2d-body-move-along-a-bezier-curve-arc-path) but the physics may be "corrupted".

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your are numerical simulating physics: `v = v + a * dt, x = x + v * dt`, with `dt` a fixed time step and `a` constructed by the sum of the forces divided by its mass (F=m*a).
In this case there are multiple ways to achieve a sine wave like motion. You could apply a sine wave like force, since a sine function has the property that it will only shift phase when you integrate/differentiate it. Or you could simulate a [simple harmonic motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion) like a mass-spring system, in which the force is proportional to the negative distance from the object to a certain point.